# Azure Cognitive Service - Computer Vision - OCR not working for Handwriting

Tags: azure, computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-services, handwriting-recognition

I am trying to use the Computer vision OCR of Azure cognitive service. I can able to do it for computer text in the image but it cannot able to recognize the text when it is a handwriting. I believe somehow there is any other way out to do it, if anybody can help me on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCR does support handwritten recognition but only for English.

Handwritten code sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-csharp#read-printed-and-handwritten-text